# Saving data from for loop in an array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to calculate an array but my for loop produces the numbers individually and then saves the last output as the vector can you please help? My code is:

```
for k= 0:0.1:3
muk = [nanmean(abs(normGsf).^(k))] 
end
```

The output I am seening is

```
muk =

 1
```

muk =

```
0.9169
```

muk =

```
0.8520
```

muk =

```
0.8011
```

muk =

```
0.7616
```

muk =

```
0.7314
```

muk =

```
0.7089
```

muk =

```
0.6932
```

muk =

```
0.6836
```

muk =

```
0.6794
```

muk =

```
0.6805
```

muk =

```
0.6866
```

muk =

```
0.6976
```

muk =

```
0.7138
```

muk =

```
0.7351
```

muk =

```
0.7621
```

muk =

```
0.7950
```

muk =

```
0.8345
```

muk =

```
0.8812
```

muk =

```
0.9359
```

muk =

```
0.9996
```

muk =

```
1.0736
```

muk =

```
1.1592
```

muk =

```
1.2582
```

muk =

```
1.3724
```

muk =

```
1.5043
```

muk =

```
1.6567
```

muk =

```
1.8327
```

muk =

```
2.0362
```

muk =

```
2.2719
```

muk =

```
2.5450
```

Comment: `ind = 1; for k= 0:0.1:3, muk(ind) = [nanmean(abs(normGsf).^(k))]; ind= ind+1;end` or `for k= 0:0.1:3, muk(k*10+1) = [nanmean(abs(normGsf).^(k))];end`

Answer (score 1):

Why not vectorize?

```
k = 0:0.1:3;
muk = nanmean(abs(normGsf)).^k;
```

I'm assuming `nanmean(abs(normGsf))` is a scalar, as in your example. Then the result `muk` is a vector with the same size as `k`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
muk = [];    
for k= 0:0.1:3
muk = [muk; nanmean(abs(normGsf).^(k))] 
end
```

This appends the new values to "muk" each time through the loop.
Note that this is not necessarily a good practice if the number of loop iterations is really large, but you are far, far from that limit.

Comment: Note that this is very inefficient, since you're creating a "growing matrix". It's much better to preallocate memory and "fill" it up afterwards. If you want to keep the loop, `muk = zeros(31,1); for k = 0:0.1:3  -- muk(k) = nanmean(abs(normGsf).^(k)); -- end`. However, Luis' vectorized approach is even better =)